# Overflow one ul element into the next

Tags: jquery

I have a number of `ul` elements on a page. I want to artifically limit the number of `li` elements it can contain. When that limit is reached, I want it to overflow to the next `ul` on the page (until it too reaches a limit and overflows to the next). And so on.

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

In the above example, I'd limit it to 4 list items, and then overflow to the next `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to do this using jquery. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is lacking detail. Are the listed elements on the page, or are you creating them? Are the div containers on the page?

Comment: What do you mean "once that div reaches a certain amount"? HTML does not limit the number of child elements (as far as I know...browsers might, but the spec does not)

Comment: ok instead of Divs I mean Listed elements inside a ul. once that reaches 4 create a new ul. The elements are generated through PHP. Im trying to organize them using JQuery. whoa downvotes :'(

Comment: @roXon ... don't yell, dude O_O

Comment: @Joseph ... I remove my yells when I'm satisfied with the question :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to do paging on a list which should be done server side with your php.

Comment: @Robert: I understood what your question was getting at and rewrote it. I hope you don't mind, but your wording was very confusing. Edit it further if I've misrepresented anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should go through each ul and insert in the first one that isn't full.

```
function insert(el){
   $('ul').each(function(_, ul){
       if($(ul).children('li').length >=4)
           return true;
       $(ul).append(el);
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have an array of element like this, try the below code

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var count = 0;
var ul;
$.each(items, function(){
  if(count == 0)
   ul = $("<ul />").appendTo(document.body);

  ul.append("<li>"+this+"</li>");

  count = (count + 1) % 4;
});
```

Comment: actually to be even more specific this is for scrollable. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html instead of divs im using ul's and listed items. which php is generating. Right now its just spitting out listed items and I need them grouped so it scrolls correctly. thanks

Comment: You could just as easily get away with modular arithmentic (`count = (count + 1) % 4;`)